# Site Offline After Saving a Setting

Tags: database

I'm trying to fix a menu problem for a client - I tried saving new settings in the Appearance tab and I got this error

PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'tester'@'88.208.252.203' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/linweb12/7/7a7.co.uk-1059923790/user/htdocs/includes/lock.inc).

What would cause this error?

Comment: I am closing the question since the answer doesn't change if instead of Drupal you were using another CMS or even plain PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MySql error. MySQL is not getting fed the correct logon information. Can you logon to mysql using your drupal credentials - either by command line or PHPMyAdmin or some other method. If you can't logon it's a credentials problem. Otherwise it's likely a path problem.

In your settings.php file, make sure everything is correct. Double check it

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'MYDATABASENAME',
      'username' => 'MYUSERNAME',
      'password' => 'MYPASSWORD',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
```

);

Comment: Hi - I think the client was doing something daft like deleting the database user while i was using the admin panel. I don't think it was anything I did!

Comment: That is where the problem is. Well create a new database user and change it in your settings.php file

Comment: @AlexLee Did you solve the problem? I came across the same issue. Firstly I couldn't login into mysql though it was correct credentials it says `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`